# Can we use glibc instead of Bionic in Android?

Tags: android, c, compiler-construction, glibc, bionic

Considering No licensing issue, enough memory and processing power can we switch back to glibc for Android from Bionic?

What are those functionalities are there in bionic which are not available with glibc?

Comment: Unclear if you've read: [Where is the Android libc documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72391241/295004) and [Is Android POSIX-compatible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27604455/295004)

Comment: Hi @MorrisonChang, So This Bionic things introduced in first place for 3major things ie License, Size, and Speed. Since in early days the smartphone lack those capacity right? So I'm curious that can we switch back to glibc for better performance as now a days smartphones have that kind of capacity (i think so). I'm new to this So Any kind of help will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Various people have web pages about having done this, but none of the ones I've found are recent or seem to be active. If you want this, I suspect you'll have to do the porting of Glibc yourself. It will be a significant task.

A significant problem is that both Bionic and Glibc provide program loading for the kernel, so you have to keep the Bionic-based code that comes with Android *carefully* segregated from your Glibc-based code. No, Glibc is not forwards-compatible from Bionic: the two libraries use incompatible symbol management strategies. Glibc versions *all* of its exported symbols, and Bionic does not.